# child div content not visible when outside parent div

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, parent-child

[image: Popout problem div]

I got 3 divs next to each other in another div.
When I hover over a div, the div popsout.
That's working but as you can see in the image the div content is cut of by his parent div (the red/pink vertical bar).
How can I make the content visible?

[Complete JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm6w4uy4/)

```
.pakket {
    width: 291px;
    height: 371px;
    border: 1px solid #F5F5EF;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/view.png) no-repeat bottom right;
    margin-left: -1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.pakket:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #5A5858;
    width: 315px;
    height: 390px;
    margin: -10px -13px -15px -12px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Create some [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or post your relevant HTML code. No Code No Solution.

Comment: I have editted the question with a jsfiddle demo

Comment: Reason is the margins you specified for .packet:hover in css. Better go with transform:scale. I have better solution with that. Is it OK to use it?

Comment: Check this is [link](http://i.imgur.com/YgsYh6N.png)

Comment: And if I use jQuery, wouldn't that be a better option?   Because transform is supported from IE 9 but I also would like a IE 8 compatibile option.  I also can't seem to get it work with transform so maybe u you can show the edited css?

Comment: why don't you remove the overflow:hidden on the .ma-main-container.col1-layout rule?

Comment: Sorry tripleb I didn't saw you're answer. It was hidden under the button show more replies. But the overflow was indeed the problem, I didn't know what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirements i think this would be more suitable.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm6w4uy4/4/)

**CSS**

```
.ma-main-container.col1-layout {
    margin: 20px;
    overflow:visible;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to post the same solution, I have removed the overflow. I never used that css-element so I didn't know what it does.. Thanx for thinking with me for a solution.

Comment: I now have an other problem with this.  
The divs are not aligned when you hover over the divs.  
I have created a new updated JSFiddle.  
You need to adjust the Result View so that you can see a minimum of 3 divs next to each other.  http://jsfiddle.net/famouswolluf/7cv52cay/1/